# Is it possible to write web-service that returns a collection of generic type? Spring 3

Tags: java, web-services, spring, generics

In my db I have a number of entity classes and I run standart CRUD operations on them via Hibernate. Its not a problem to create generic dao class to make all main operations with classes. For example, in dao I have methods which look like this:

```
<T> List<T> loadAll(Class clazz)
```

Now I want to expose these methods to web-service client via Spring 3 operated web-service.

The only way I see is to implement web-methods for all entities i.e. write a class that looks like...

```
class BookResponse { List<BookEntity> books; }
```

... and return this in corresponding web-method "BookResponse getAllBooks()". This will ruin my attemts to make a code simplier by using dao with generics.

Is there are any other ways?
How can I do this without implementing web-methods for ALL my entities? 
If generic web-service is not possible may be there are some other ways to resolve this task in a simple way?

UPDATE:
At the moment I am trying to implement a response class which should look like

```
public class ServiceResponse<T>{

    @XmlElementWrapper( name = "data" )
    @XmlElements( @XmlElement(name = "a", type = EntityA.class), @XmlElement(name = "b", type = EntityB.class) )
    private List<T> data = new ArrayList<T>(  );

    //getters,setters
}
```

So I want to be able to insert a list of any entities mapped with annotations to this response. This produces no erros, but the response given me by web-service is empty.

Comment: what serialization are you going to use? is it going to be RESTful or wsdl-based web service?

Comment: at the moment I use WSDL-based web-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need a new POJO "GenericEntity" which can hold the information of any domain entity class instance.
It would hold a type string and an arbitrary/generic list of named attributes.
It can then be used to represent any of your real domain entities

e.g.
  type = Book
  attributes = (title=Order of the Phoenix, author=J K Rowling)

e.g.
  type = Car
  attributes = (make=Renault, model=Clio)

These examples show String attributes so you'll have to sort out if this is good enough or if you need strong typing - it's possible but harder.

You can then expose your "GenericEntity" via web services, allowing clients to make calls in and specify which domain entity they wish to search for, and even allow them to specify search criteria too.
Adds and deletes could be done in a similar way.

HTH,

David